# ASP.NET 4.0 Url Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, query-string, url-routing

I am trying to use Rounting in ASP.NET 4.0

This is my code:(global.asax file)

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.MapPageRoute("recordingDemo", "recording.aspx", "~/About.aspx?sub=recordingdemo");
    }
```

In About.aspx:

```
 if (Request.QueryString["sub"] != null)
 {
      switch (Request.QueryString["sub"].ToString())
      {
                    case "demo":
                        multiviewRecording.SetActiveView(viewDemo);
                        break;
      }
      ..........
}
```

The problem is that I don't have anymore *querystring* in *About* page.

What I want to do is:  on link *recording.aspx*(this page doesn't exists in my page) I want to open the page *About.aspx?sub=recordingdemo*

It is possible to do something like this with Url Rounting?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution:

```
 routes.MapPageRoute("recordingDemo", "recording.aspx", "~/About.aspx?sub=recordingdemo",, true, new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary{{"sub", "demo"}});
```

And in About.aspx :

> string route = Page.RouteData.Values["sub"].ToString();

I hope that my solution will help some other people.